# Use sub row only for certain head rows in excel pivot table from a cube

Tags: excel, pivot

I have the following pivot table:

[image]

Underneath "Sales" and "Gross Profit" I want to add a sub-row, which breaks down the figure by department. However I do not want "Other Income" or "Expenses" to be broken down by department. When I add department to the pivot as a second sub row, it shows like this:

[image]

Is there a way to only have the sub row under "Sales" and "Gross Profit"

Thanks,
Scott